# Maven deployment location vs download location

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, pom.xml, nexus

I have a problem setting up things correctly; my end goal is to pull artifacts from one nexus (I'm going to refer to it as Nexus1) and deploy to another nexus (Nexus2), two are hosted in different locations with different domains.

Here's my settings.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
<distributionManagement>
  <repository>
     <id>deployment</id>
     <name>Internal Releases</name>
     <url>http://Nexus2/content/repositories/releases/</url>
  </repository>
  <snapshotRepository>
     <id>deployment</id>
     <name>Internal Releases</name>
     <url>http://Nexus2/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
  </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
  <mirrors>
    <mirror>
      <id>company-central</id>
      <name>CompanyCentral</name>
      <url>http://Nexus1/content/groups/public/</url>
      <mirrorOf>central</mirrorOf>
    </mirror>
  </mirrors>
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>default-repositories</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <repositories>
        <repository>
          <id>core-releases</id>
          <url>http://Nexus1/content/repositories/core-release</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>core-snapshots</id>
          <url>http://Nexus1/content/repositories/core-snapshot</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>releases</id>
          <url>http://Nexus1/content/repositories/releases</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
          <id>snapshots</id>
          <url>http://Nexus1/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
          <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
          </releases>
          <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
            <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
          </snapshots>
        </repository>
      </repositories>
    </profile>
    <profile>
         <id>inject-liferay-properties</id>
         <properties>
           <liferay.auto.deploy.dir.val>/Users/dmadathil/Documents/Portal/workspace/X-Portal-11.0.0/bundles/deploy</liferay.auto.deploy.dir.val>
           <liferay.app.server.deploy.dir.val>/Users/dmadathil/Documents/Portal/workspace/X-Portal-11.0.0/bundles</liferay.app.server.deploy.dir.val>
           <liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir.val>/Users/dmadathil/Documents/Portal/workspace/X-Portal-11.0.0/bundles/tomcat-7.0.42/lib</liferay.app.server.lib.global.dir.val>
           <liferay.app.server.portal.dir.val>/Users/dmadathil/Documents/Portal/workspace/X-Portal-11.0.0/bundles/tomcat-7.0.42/webapps/ROOT</liferay.app.server.portal.dir.val>
         </properties>
     </profile>    
 </profiles>
 <activeProfiles>
   <activeProfile>inject-liferay-properties</activeProfile>
 </activeProfiles>
</settings>
```

And here's my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>super-pom</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0</version>
    </parent>

    <artifactId>covlogs</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>log4j-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
                    <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.platform.group.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>group-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.company.platform.user.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>user-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>


    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.5.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.company.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>slf4j-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.12</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.company.platform.group.client</groupId>
                <artifactId>group-client</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.company.platform.user.client</groupId>
                <artifactId>user-client</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.9</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.json</groupId>
                <artifactId>json</artifactId>
                <version>20141113</version>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.8.2</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.4.201502262128</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>pre-unit-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>post-unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </repository>
        <!--<repository>
            <id>core-releases</id>
            <url>http://Nexus1/content/repositories/core-release</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>core-snapshots</id>
            <url>http://Nexus1/content/repositories/core-snapshot</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>releases</id>
            <url>http://Nexus1/content/repositories/releases</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>snapshots</id>
            <url>http://Nexus1/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>-->
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>spring-releases</id>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-release</url>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

The problem that I'm facing is that every time I build the project it still tries to upload to Nexus1 instead of Nexus2!!

EDIT: Here's a sample error message from Jenkins' output console:

```
ERROR: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not transfer artifact com.company:covlogs:jar:0.0.2-20150928.201829-1 from/to snapshots (http://Nexus1/content/repositories/core-snapshot/): Failed to transfer file: http://Nexus1/content/repositories/core-snapshot/com/company/covlogs/0.0.2-SNAPSHOT/covlogs-0.0.2-20150928.201829-1.jar. Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.
```

I'm still new to maven, and I'm not sure what's going wrong. I've been banging my head for a couple of days now on this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT2: Steps I've taken, I've added the `<distributionManagement>` block hoping it would fix the issue, but that didn't work.

I've also added `maven-deploy-plugin` to pom.xml, but that didn't do anything either.

EDIT3: For Jenkins I'm using Maven Release plug-in to setup where I want the artifacts to be deployed to:

[image]

Comment: You problem seemed to be here: `Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized.`...you didn't configure your settings.xml correctly with the appropriate credentials. Apart from that why do you need to use one Nexus and deploy to an other ? Furthermore your settings.xml setup looks wrong. For downloading artifacts you only need to change settings like [this](https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/2.8/reference/maven-sect-single-group.html) and the target where you deploy is defined by distributionManagement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. As I've said in my post the problem is that it's deploying to Nexus1 and not Nexus2. The reason why I want to pull from Nexus1 and deploy to Nexus2 is because Nexus1 is old and frankly just a huge mess and we're slowly moving to a newly built Nexus on a AWS (which the old one isn't on). All projects are still fetching artifacts from the old Nexus. I'm trying to test deployment on the new Nexus (Nexus2) and therefore I'm trying to do what I've mentioned above.

Comment: So to make things easier to understand my problem is that the job is trying to deploy the artifacts to the old nexus (Nexus1) instead of the new Nexus (Nexus2) and I think that's why I'm getting the 401 error. (I think the Jenkins plugin should take care of the credentials on the new Nexus).